# asp.net core routing variable

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, routes

Is there a way to get a value from a route defined on the controller without adding the parameter to all http methods?

Example of what I'm trying to do.

```
calling localhost/api/test/client
```

```cs
[Route("api/{somevar}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ClientController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly MainContext fContext;
    private string fSomeVar;

    public ClientController(MainContext pContext)
    {
        fContext = pContext;
        fSomeVar = somevar; <-- Is there a way to get "test" from the route?
    }

    // GET: api/Client
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ClientDH>>> GetClients()
    {
        // use fSomeVar here.
    }

    // GET: api/Client
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ClientDH>>> GetClients(string somevar)
    {
        // this works but I'm trying to avoid changing all the methods in all controllers.
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add two different routes to the controller, such as `[Route("api/test/[controller]")]` and `[Route("api/prod/[controller]")]`? Then you could add a method to find the path variable programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is below:

1.You can use IHttpContextAccessor  to get the route value from the http request, code as below:

```
 public DemoController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {      
            fSomeVar = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["somevar"].ToString();
        }
```

and in startup.cs, you need to configure:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

2.Demo:

```
    [Route("api/{somevar}/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DemoController : ControllerBase
    {
        private string fSomeVar;
        public DemoController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {      
            fSomeVar = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["somevar"].ToString();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Demo1()
        {    
            try
            {
                return Ok("Id: " + fSomeVar);
            }
            catch
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }

        [HttpGet("demo2/{id1}/{id2}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Demo2(string id1, int id2)
        {
            try
            {
                return Ok("Id1: " + id1 + ", Id2: " + id2+ ", Id3: " + fSomeVar);
            }
            catch
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That works great. Thank you! Very thorough answer!! I love the result demo :)